# What photos do I love?

Tags: word, cipher, visual

This one may be my favorite... I tend to linger, unable to stop admiring it... I wonder what that person is thinking down there...

[image: Cliffside]

Ahh my favorite city... a classic...

[image: City]

With summer coming up this brings back great memories... Can't wait to get s'more of these shots...

[image: Ocean]

**What type of photos do I like the most?**

- Feedback on drawing puzzles would be appreciated, I'm still testing the water to see how people feel about them. I want to ultimately make some more elaborate hand drawn puzzles.

Comment: Landscape photo? what else :P?

Comment: Oh snap, I've been found out ;)

Comment: @AlwaysConfused But the first and last photos are portrait...

Comment: @AlwaysConfused, no, two of those are portrait.  :P  $\quad$

Comment: Argh, beat me to it..  @F1Krazy.  LOL.

Comment: :D :D Not orientation of photo margin...; but from subject all 3 are landscape; though last one is literally not "land", so better to tell seascape. However only is that the puzzle?

Comment: Mobile users won't see the `FXL` tooltip in the first image...

Comment: @Mordechai Yeah unfortunately not

Comment: Even after Beasty Gerbil told me about FXL tooltip in comment, it was not possible for me to solve. I don't know what is FXL (Google says Field X-Ray Lab). Also my idea about binary number is just up to school computer classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You like

> SKYLINES (And indeed each photo has one)

The first picture

> If you hover over it (I tend to linger) you get FXL. Joining the dots on the picture gives:
>
>  [image]
>
> And there are 13 dots. This clues rot13.
>
> Applying that to FXL gives **SKY**

The second picture (solved with help from Tech in chat)

> The town name is BINARY backwards. Taking a window as 0 and a bold line as 1 we get:
>
> 01001100 01001001
>
> Which is binary for **LI**

The last picture (solved by Sconibulus in chat)

> Taking the birds as morse ('s'more') gives:
>
> -. .
>
> Which is morse for **NE**

Putting this together:

> **SKYLINE**

Answer (score 0):

Not a final answer but just a litle try.

> Seems you like to photograph situations where natural objects appears to be in straight line. Especially 3 or more objects in a straight line or almost straight line.  We can draw straightline through any 2 objects; but for three-objects, co-linearity is quite less-probable, so rarer shots.

..................

> Example:
>
>  [image: Stars over the plateau]
>  On this image of stars seen from the plateau; some co-linear stars being seen.
>
>
>  [image: Cityscape]
>  On the cityscape,  lot such similar straight lines could be found. 
>  
>  [image: Seascape]
>  The seascape showing a row of bird in almost straight line.

Comment: This isn't really much of an answer, and lacks an explanation which the final answer has.

Comment: Note the [tag:cipher] tag. For instance, if you hover over the first image you get FXL which is [rot13](http://www.rot13.com/) for 'SKY', this is a lot more complicated that just that. For instance the city name is 'BINARY' backwards

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I'm seeing so; many of the puzzles in this size are very big and complicated and often seeking multiple folds of complex decryption.

Comment: It's not overly complicated, but again, this is not what I am going for. You'll be able to deduce a word from them as indicated by the word tag. - If you take those lines you drew on the 1st image, and just connect the dots on the two cohesive sets of stars you'll find the clue to the cipher Gerbil uncovered ;)